# Yocto: LICENSE="CLOSED"

Tags: yocto

I am attempting to create a recipe that includes a custom python package written by us and sourced from a git server on our LAN. I'm running into an issue with defining the license. There is no license. From what I've read, in this situation these license fields should be used in the recipe:

```
   LICENSE="CLOSED"
   LIC_FILES_CHKSUM=""
```

and this should be all that is required.

Trying to build the recipe gives the following error when the recipe is parsed:

```
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES '<recipe>' <recipe> was skipped: because it has a restricted license not whitelisted in LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST
```

My understanding is that the CLOSED license should not require whitelisting as it is coded as a specific case, but I have tried adding the recipe to the whitelist without success.

Should I be using some other license in this situation? Should I be using LICENSE_FLAGS? I've tried to find a solution in the documentation without success, perhaps due to my noob status and the steepness of the learning curve.

Can anyone help take the edge of the curve for me?

Comment: You don't need to set LIC_FILES_CHKSUM when closed license is used. Maybe try to remove it. You could also add [custom license](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-LICENSE_PATH) to your code.

Comment: just whitelist the license for this specific package

Comment: consider following: [How to handle the LICENSE field when there is no license file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60726034/how-to-handle-the-license-field-when-there-is-no-license-file/66407303#66407303)

Comment: @Nayfe: That link is no longer valid.  Consider this one: https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-LICENSE_PATH

Answer (score 2):

After deleting tmp, sstate-cache and downloads I tried removing LIC_FILES_CHKSUM then creating a custom license, neither approach worked. I then ran the build from scratch without the custom recipe, then added it back and now both techniques work as expected.

It appears there was still some state information related to earlier incorrect values of the license fields hanging about, perhaps in cache.

This is the first time deleting tmp, downloads and sstate-cache has not brought the system back to a truely clean state after I have futzed around with things exploring how they work. bitbake -c clean/clean_all have never done a reasonable job.

Thanks for the helpful comments.