# How to handle the LICENSE field when there is no license file?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

What if there is no license file as e.g. in this repo: https://github.com/jwrdegoede/rtl8189ES_linux. The license is given in each file header instead. How do I account for that appropriately in a `bitbake` recipe?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LIC_FILES_CHKSUM` can point to any file that defines the license.  If there isn't a dedicated license file then you can point it at a fragment of a `README` or `main.c` or similar.  For example from `ppp.bb`:

```
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://pppd/ccp.c;beginline=1;endline=29;md5=e2c4[...]"
```

Answer (score 0):

example to handle project with no license file provided by taking license from the script file header:

```
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://waf-light;beginline=6;endline=30;md5=d24c6f4d54f0156e838f29af79a3bb6b"
```

beware, MD5 checksum must be taken from the license text only but the whole script file.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution for me was as below.

```
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = ""
```

Worked in **Yocto 4.3, nanbield**.